# Run Get-ADForest from command line

Tags: powershell

I do not have an interactive powershell console.
I just can run windows commands.

I want to run Get-ADForest directly from command line.

Here is what i have tried:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Get-ADForest -Identity mydomain"
```

I get this error (sorry, french server):

```
Le terme ??Get-ADForest?? n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande
```

I tried to do this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Import-module Active Directory"
```

But it does not work anymore.

What i want to do is to fetch admin (519) SID

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried combining `Import-Module` and the command? The PowerShell version (2.0 vs 3.0+) determines if you need to import the module manually. The module is named `ActiveDirectory`.

Try:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Import-module ActiveDirectory; ((Get-ADForest).RootDomain | Get-ADDomain).DomainSid.Value + '-519'"
```

If it still fails I would suggest verifying if you have the module installed on the machine.

Comment: It fails. Is there another way to get the "Entreprise Admin" SID ?

Comment: Fails with? What does the error say? Do you have the module?

Comment: You asked how to run the cmdlet.. see updated answer for suggestion on how to get the SID

Comment: Yes, as the reason for why you need the cmdlet. The title and problem itself is how to make the cmdlet work. We don't provide free scripts here, we help you fix your problems so you can write them yourself and learn. Doesn't matter anymore. Good luck